# This loop makes a whole new label each loop... Why?

Tags: python, tkinter

Every time it loops it creates a whole new label, rather that just refresh.

```
from tkinter import *
import psutil

def task():
   e = Entry(root)
   e.pack()

   e.delete(0, END)
   e.insert(0,psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None))
   s = e.get()
   root.after(500, task)  # reschedule event in .5 seconds


root = Tk()
root.after(500, task)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code does not create any labels. Maybe you mean entry?

Comment: Where is the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you call the `task` function, it creates a new Entry object and deletes the content of the new object instead of using one global Entry.

First of all create the entry:

```
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
```

Then make sure that your task function is using the one and only global Entry `e` without creating any new ones:

```
def task():
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None))
    root.after(500, task)
```

and then you can call the function and let it call itself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just started learning to code about two weeks ago. I'm still hung up on the basics... So thanks again.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark the answer as accepted if that solves it or ask for more help if you run into problems with my code.